# Haskell: Num instance of non-concrete type

Tags: haskell, types, instance, typeclass

```
data Vector a = Vector a a a deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Vector where
    fmap f (Vector x y z) = Vector (f x) (f y) (f z)
```

So far so good.

```
instance Num ((Num a) => Vector a) where
    negate = fmap negate
```

Doesn't work. I tried many different variations on that first line but GHC keeps complaining. I want to make *a `Vector` containing numbers* an instance of `Num`; surely this should be possible? Otherwise I would have to make an instance for `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, etc. all with the same definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
instance Num a => Num (Vector a) where
   negate = fmap negate
```

Consider writing other methods too.

(You can write `deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)` if you turn on `-XDeriveFunctor`.)

Comment: So it was just the syntax I hadn't got right—Thanks, I should have figured this one out myself… I thought I had already tried that, evidently not.

Comment: If you're doing guess and check then you've probably gone beyond the point of productivity.  Finding a solid reference would be a huge time saver.

Comment: @Mk12, and example of a solid reference for typeclasses is [the appropriate section of LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-102), and also [that of RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: You're right. I think I had tried this first, but I was mising the parentheses, and for some reason I was thinking that you couldn't do this so I was going to ask here to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a bad idea to make `Vector` an instance of `Num`. Here's the declaration of `Num`:

```
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
```

`+` and `-` and `negate` are no problem. One can define `*` as cross product, but only for 3-vectors, and this is really stretching it. `abs`, `signum` and `fromInteger` have no meaningful definitions.

In short, it is possible to shoehorn `Vector` into `Num`, but the result is not nice.

You may want to explore alternative type class hierarchies which replace the standard Prelude ones, e.g. the [Numeric prelude](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Prelude).

Comment: Of course, one could make `(*)` and the other ones lexicographic just like `(+)` and `(-)`. Then `negate` is equivalent to `(-1 *)`

Comment: Of course you *can* define these operations *somehow* (everything results in a zero-vector, for example). The point is to come up with useful definitions. Component-wise `*` is not useful for vectors (as in, components of a vector-space).

Comment: `(+)` and `(-)` can be defined for Vectors. I don't think it's a stretch to implement `negate` and `abs` as a simple component mapping. This seems more practical to me than defining ugly operators like `<+>` and functions like `vnegate`; is there a better solution? Is using `Num` only bad in that it's not completely semantically meaninful? I'll take a look at Numeric prelude, but I wouldn't have thought it would be this hard to elegantly implement vectors in Haskell.

Comment: `negate` is OK, as it is just multiplication by scalar (-1). `abs` is dubious, there's no meaningful vector-space operator that corresponds to it. OK so you can define `abs` in any way you want, it does not have to be meaningful. But no matter what you do, you simply cannot make `(*)` denote the vector-by-scalar multiplication. This is, in my opinion, *the* reason to not bother with shoehorning vectors into `Num`.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean… I'm wondering, if I'm not going to be instancing `Num` anyway, if maybe I should just make things a lot simpler and represent Vectors as `Num a => [a]` rather than making a new type.

Comment: I always thought the modulus operator of a vector mapped very well to the "abs" function. In many mathematical formulas it happens that a non-vector version uses `abs` while a vectorial version uses the vector modulus.

Comment: @Viclib Num's abs has type `a->a`, but the absolute value of a vector is not a vector, it's a scalar.